# Sink windowing table to db

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

i'm currently running an instance of confluent-kafka with an mqtt source connector. I'm able to query data and create various stream/table, the problem is that:
when i create a windowing query to create a table, for example counting table, the key of this table is malformed and i can't safe it to external db, example:
[image]

It is possible to use only ksqldb to query and push data of windowing query to db?

Comment: Just for clarity: the key is not `malformed`. The key includes the window. What version of ksqlDB are you using?

Comment: I'm using confluent 0.6.0

Comment: It would help if you could show what data is in the topic as text, not an image, your ksql query, and what you expect to write to the database